# Va y avoir pensé

Tags: verbes, futur, futur-proche

Le pire meilleur ami d'Alexandra Larochelle :

Azalée, Noah et Marilou discutent de leur projet, ils font partie du Club des p'tits ingénieurs.

> —  Une petite voiture électrique ?
>
> —  C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école **va** y **avoir pensé**. (1)

*Avoir pensé* veut dire qu'il s'agit du passé alors que le verbe *va* indique le futur. Je ne comprends pas ce mélange, pourquoi l'ensemble est au futur ?

> —  C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école **va** y **penser**. (2)

Quelle est la différence entre les phrases (1) et (2) ?

Answer (score 3):

*C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école **va** y avoir pensé*.

Plus prosaïquement, ***va*** reste un futur: le futur proche où va se produire une connaissance que je redoute :
‹ils y avaient pensé ! ›

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe « aller » ne marque le [futur proche](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-12541.php) que dans la seconde phrase. Dans la première, « aller », parce qu'il est suivi de l'infinitif passé  n'est plus utilisé en tant que semi-auxiliaire mais en tant que modal. Sa valeur modale est selon le contexte, la probabilité dans le passé  ou l'expression de la crainte, de la prémonition, de la spéculation. Cependant cette construction n'indique pas un usage de  « aller » en tant que modal dans tous les cas ; tout dépend du contexte.

- Je vais avoir fini dans un instant. (futur proche ou imminent ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller))
- Je ne vais pas avoir fini à temps, il vaut mieux que je me fasse aider. (*futur proche ou probabilité dans le futur (rendu possible à cause de la négation)*)

> —  C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école va y avoir pensé. (1)

- C'est sûr **qu'il y a des chances** qu'une équipe d'une autre école **y ait pensé**. (*équivalent à (1) au moyen de « il y a des chances que + subjonctif passé*)
- C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école **y aura pensé**. (*équivalent à (1) au moyen du futur antérieur*)

*Probabilité dans le passé*

- Le principe coule de source, ils vont l'avoir découvert, il y a peu de doute.

*Crainte*

- Regarde cette fumée qui vient de l'intérieur de la grange, il va avoir mis le feu à la paille !

*Prémonition*

- Encore une fois il ne va pas  avoir fait le feu, je le sens.

Je ne trouve pas de référence pour justifier les assertions ci-dessus.

> (**LBU édition 14 § 888**)
> b) Emplois particuliers.
> 1 °
> Pour énoncer une explication probable (comp. § 887, h, 3°) :
> Pauvre enfant ! On t'a maltraitée, c'est ta femme de chambre qui t'AURA TRAHIE (MUSSET, Il ne faut jurer de rien, III, 4). — Je viens donc de tomber à mon
> insu dans quelque action qui vous AURA DÉPLU ? (STENDHAL, Rouge, II, 31.) —
> J'AURAI LAISSÉ mes lunettes en haut.

L'équivalence montrée précédemment n'est pas toujours parfaite, peut-être parce que l'emploi d'« aller » pour la probabilité est plutôt du registre familier.

- Pauvre enfant ! On t'a maltraitée, c'est ta femme de chambre qui va t'avoir trahie. (*apparemment moins clair*)

Comment: OK, merci. _Je ne trouve pas référence pour justifier les assertions ci-dessus._ Moi non plus, je n'ai pas trouvé d'explications...

Comment: j'ai un peu de mal avec l'exemple "crainte" qui me semble boiteux, bien que n'arrive pas identifier pourquoi... peut être comme la vue de la fumée est au présent, le *va avoir* est un peu étrange dans ce cas.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprend pas : l'antécédent de « y » n'a rien à voir dans le sens de « aller avoir pensé » ; par exemple, le problème est le même dans « C'est sûr qu'une équipe d'une autre école va avoir pensé à une petite voiture électrique. ». De plus, l'antécédent n'est jamais un verb : le pronom (pro- (pour) le nom) ne peut remplacer qu'un nom, un groupe nominal, ou une proposition nominale.

Comment: @Lambie On n'en trouve pas pour « pensé » parce que ça n'est encore arrivé à personne d'y penser ; mais il y en a beaucoup pour « fait »  et « fini » : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22va%20avoir%20fait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=va+avoir+fini&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cva%20avoir%20fini%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cva%20avoir%20fini%3B%2Cc0 . « Marche » et « fonctionne » ne signifient rien en grammaire, absolument rien.

Comment: @Lambie On ne peut pas, c'est  juste, pas « avoir pens**er** », mais « avoir pens**é** », si. Regardez la référence dans la réponse (TLFi, « vais avoir fini ») ; si on peut utiliser « fini » on peut bien utiliser n"importe quel autre participe passé , et si on peut utiliser la première personne ( « vais ») on peut aussi utiliser la troisième (sauf cas de verbe défectif). Justement c'est « avoir penser » qui n'existe pas, ce n'est pas une forme verbale ; « penser » ne peut exister dans cette combinaison qu'en tant que participe passé (« aller avoir pensé ») ; de même pour « avoir ».

Comment: avoir pensé est un passé. Donc, l'antécédent **verbal** ne peut pas être le verbe aller au présent. On pourrait avoir: "va y penser" ou "y aura pensé" ou "y aurait pensé" (comme dans la réponse) d'accord.

Comment: @Lambie Quelle est votre définition de « antécédent verbal » ? Ça n'existe pas pour moi, tnat que vous n'en donnez pas une définition précise. Vous ne voyez pas que « vais avoir fini » est grammatical ? Il faut que « va avoir pensé » soit grammaticalement correct ; de plus c'est sémantiquement correct.